# Entity Framework Core - set Table1.Column = Table2.Column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using .Net Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core

I have the following models:

```
public Employee {
      ...
      public string PositionName { get; set; }
      public int PositionId { get; set; }
      ...
}

public Position {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where Position.Id relates to Employee.PositionId

My goal is to return IEnumerable of Employee to the user with Employee.PositionName = Position.Name from the Position Table (Very small table - 10 rows).

I achieved that with brute force using:

```
   IEnumerable<Employee> employees = await repository.GetAllAsync();
   IEnumerable<Position> positions = await positionRepository.GetAllAsync();

   foreach (Employee emp in employees)
   {
       emp.PositionName = positions.FirstOrDefault(position => position.Id == employee.PositionId).Name;
   }
```

If both tables are very large then this is a terrible solution.

Any recommendations?

Comment: CompanyPositionId and PositionId are different from each other?

Comment: The tables should have a relationship, then this would be trivial (if I understand your problem correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  I had not seen them yet before I figured this out.

I needed to build a one to many relationship in the models.

There are several ways to do this.  I chose to create a "has a" relationship where Employee "has a" Position.

```
   public Employee 
   {
      public int Id {get; set;}
     ...other props here....

      // EF will automatically create a foreign key because the Position Model has Id
      public Position Position{ get; set; }
   }

   public Position {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

> NOTE: EF will automatically create the Foreign key relationship
> between Employee and Position tables as long as the Position
> table/model has an appropriate Id (Id or PositionId).

When seeding my DB I simply created Employees and their Positions like this which populated both tables:

```
       using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            context.Employee.AddRange(new Employee[] {
                new Employee{
                    ..other fields initialized here...
                    Position = new Position { Name = "Manager" }
                },
                new Employee{
                      ..other fields initialized here...
                    Position = new Position { Name = "Supervisor" }
                }

            });

            context.SaveChanges();


            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

> Note: Obviously, it's better to create the Position table and populate
> it separately.  I would have to create an employee for every position
> type using the approach above.

After studying further I finally figured out a better way to configure this related Entity relationship by adding a Foreign Key Id for the Position.Id in the Employee Model:

```
   public Employee 
   {
      public int Id {get; set;}
     ...other props here....

      // EF will treat PositionId as the Foreign Key
      public int PositionId {get; set;}
      public Position Position{ get; set; }
   }

   public Position {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

Then, I first seeded the Position Table. I stored the Ids of each row I created in variables for setting the Employee.PositionId below. (such as managerId, ceoId)

Then I seeded the Employee table as follows:

```
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            context.Employee.AddRange(new Employee[] {
                new Employee{
                    ..other fields initialized here...
                    PositionId = managerId
                },
                new Employee{
                      ..other fields initialized here...
                    PositionId = ceoId
                }

            });

            context.SaveChanges();

            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

**NEXT PROBLEM: How to get Linq to return the related Position entity.**

Then I found some help here on how to load the related data from the Position table:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

DbSet dbEntity = context.Set();

**This Linq statement will not bring back Related Data**

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = dbEntity.ToList();
```

**Enter Eager Loading**
To do that we need to use Eager Loading by using the "Include" Linq extension:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = dbEntity.Include(e => e.Position).ToList();
```

Thoughts? Ideas? Let me know if you have a better solution.

Comment: A raw SQL query might also work.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var filtered = employees.Where(x => positions.Any(n=>n.Name.Equals(x.PositionName)));
```

A bit off-topic but it is good to use .ConfigureAwait(false); to make sure nothing unexpected happen during data fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the ConfigureAwait suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a new Model for the data you want form Both tables let say `NewModel` then query it :

```
var query = from emp in your_context.repository
                    join pos in your_context.positionRepository
                    on emp.PositionId  equals pos.Id
                    select new NewModel
                    {
                        // any data you want 
                        EmpName = emp.Emp_Name,
                        EmpPos = pos.Emp_Pos,

                    };
        List<NewModel> emplist = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Great idea.  I went with my answer in the end as it has worked nicely.  I just needed to refactor my model and use eager loading on the "has a" entity relationships.